# How to use the outer type for a generic type parameter in trait impls

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a minimal example as below.

There are two traits, `TraitA` and `TraitB`. `TraitB` has a generic function that uses `TraitA` as type parameter. `TraitB` has to be object safe so I mark the function with `where Self: Sized`. It works fine so far.

If I have a struct `MyStruct<A: TraitA>`, and I want to implement `TraitB` for it. The `impl` block will have `impl<A: TraitA> TraitB for MyStruct<A>`. But for the `generic_func`, the compiler complains that A is already used. I could not get the code to compile as I could not figure out what to put in the place of '???' in the example.

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

// One trait
trait TraitA {}

// The other trait that has one generic function that uses TraitA
trait TraitB {
    fn generic_func<A: TraitA>(self) where Self: Sized;
}

// TraitB needs to be object safe
fn foo(a: &dyn TraitB) {
    
}

// The generic struct that uses TraitA, but needs to implement TraitB as well.
struct MyStruct<A: TraitA>(PhantomData<A>);

impl<A: TraitA> TraitB for MyStruct<A> {
    // What should I put as ???. It should refer to A.
    fn generic_func<???>(self) where Self: Sized {
    }
}
```

Rust playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4eff9e5a6fded93e03a090890f84e983

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any letter will do. `C`, `D`, `Potato`, etc., Rust doesn't care whether the generic variables have the same *name*, just that they're used in the same way (i.e. whatever you name it needs to be `: TraitA`)

```
impl<A: TraitA> TraitB for MyStruct<A> {
  fn generic_func<Potato: TraitA>(self) where Self: Sized {
  }
}
```

As you've written it, `TraitB` demands a `generic_func` that works for *every* type which implements `TraitA`. If you want it to work for a specific one, you need to write your trait differently.

```
trait TraitB {
  type MyA: TraitA;
  fn generic_func(self);
}

impl<A: Trait> TraitB for MyStruct<A> {
  type MyA = A;
  fn generic_func(self) { ... }
}
```

Now, inside of the trait, `Self::MyA` refers to the *specific type* which you're implementing this trait to work with.

Comment: True. But is there any way to ensure that the type paramter for the generic function is the same as the type parameter for the struct? (i.e. `Potato` is the same as `A` in the example)

Comment: See my edit. As you've written your trait, `generic_func` must work for *all* valid types. You can change your trait definition if that's not what you intended.